# How to create dynamic jenkins pipeline with separate container for every stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have static working jenkins pipelines:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7'))
    timeout(time: 90, unit: 'MINUTES')
  }
  stages {
    stage ('1. Prepare') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml agentPod()
          defaultContainer 'agent'
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          echo "Prepare pipeline"
        }
      }
    }
    stage ('2. Check') {
      parallel {
        stage('Runs on master') {
          agent {
            kubernetes {
              yaml agentPod("500m", "500Mi", "100m", "200Mi")
              defaultContainer 'agent'
            }
          }
          steps {
            echo "Running on master"
          }
        }
        stage('Runs on agent1') {
          agent {
            kubernetes {
              yaml agentPod("500m", "500Mi", "100m", "200Mi")
              defaultContainer 'agent'
            }
          }
          steps {
            echo "Running on agent1"
          }
        }
        stage('Runs on agent2') {
          agent {
            kubernetes {
              yaml agentPod("500m", "500Mi", "100m", "200Mi")
              defaultContainer 'agent'
            }
          }
          steps {
            echo "Running on agent2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I need to create the same pipeline but use a dynamic function. I try to use several ideas, but every time it doesn't work. Very important is that for every stage I need create a separate kubernetes pod (with kaniko image to build new image). I try to use something like this but it desn't work.

```
def generateStage(podLabel) {
  return {
    agent {
      kubernetes {
        yaml agentPod("500m", "500Mi", "100m", "200Mi")
        defaultContainer 'agent'
      }
    }
    steps {
      echo "Running on ${podLabel}"
    }
  }
}

def parallelStagesMap = [:]

pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7'))
    timeout(time: 90, unit: 'MINUTES')
  }
  stages {
    stage ('1. Prepare') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml agentPod()
          defaultContainer 'agent'
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          def agents = ['master', 'agent1', 'agent2']
          parallelStagesMap = agents.collectEntries {
            ["Runs on ${it}" : generateStage(it)]
          }
          echo "Prepare pipeline"
        }
      }
    }
    stage ('2. Check') {
      parallel parallelStagesMap 
    }
  }
}
```

because after I execute this code I see this error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

/var/jenkins_home/jobs/app/jobs/pipeline/branches/PR-14476/builds/24/libs/e647be597f45b6129772d69874a82199dfce9ad821d01ce80c7a153b2c310c04/vars/dashboardPipelineTemplate.groovy: 46: Expected a block for parallel @ line 46, column 7.
         parallel parallelStagesMap 
         ^

/var/jenkins_home/jobs/app/jobs/pipeline/branches/PR-14476/builds/24/libs/e647be597f45b6129772d69874a82199dfce9ad821d01ce80c7a153b2c310c04/vars/dashboardPipelineTemplate.groovy: 46: No stages specified @ line 46, column 7.
         parallel parallelStagesMap 
         ^

/var/jenkins_home/jobs/app/jobs/pipeline/branches/PR-14476/builds/24/libs/e647be597f45b6129772d69874a82199dfce9ad821d01ce80c7a153b2c310c04/vars/dashboardPipelineTemplate.groovy: 46: No stages specified @ line 46, column 7.
         parallel parallelStagesMap 
         ^
```

Does anyone have any idea how to build something like this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Once you move into `Scripted Pipeline Syntax` you can no longer use `Declarative Pipeline Syntax` like `agent`. So instead of using the `agent` directive try using [Pod Template step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-using-the-pipeline-step). Something like [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/kaniko.groovy). Your `generateStage(podLabel)` function should look something like the one below.

```
def generateStage(podLabel) {
  return {
    stage(podLabel) {
        podTemplate {
            node(POD_LABEL) {
                // pipeline steps...
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they create the function you propose, the same problem still exists `Expected a block for parallel`. It looks like `parallel parallelStagesMap` don't work properly. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: First, get your parallel Pipeline working with something simple and then expand on top of it. I can't exactly tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to how to correctly create a dynamic parallel Jenkins pipeline with separate container. I added an extra condition to show you how to add "extra" logic to create an extra condition, that not all elements in the list should proceed.

```
def generateStage(podLabel) {
  return {
    stage("Runs on ${podLabel}") {
      podTemplate(yaml: agentPod("500m", "500Mi", "100m", "200Mi")){
        node(POD_LABEL) {
          echo "Running on ${podLabel}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def parallelStagesMap = [:]

pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7'))
    timeout(time: 90, unit: 'MINUTES')
  }
  stages {
    stage ('1. Prepare') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml agentPod()
          defaultContainer 'agent'
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          def agents = ['master', 'agent1', 'agent2']
          agents.each{
            if (it != "master") {
              parallelStagesMap["Runs on ${it}"] = generateStage(it)
            }
          }
          echo "Prepare pipeline"
        }
      }
    }
    stage ('2. Check') {
      steps {
        script {
          parallel parallelStagesMap 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```